# How to stream video in a specific location of PC to android phone over internet?

Tags: windows, android, remote-access, video-streaming

I have a Windows 8 PC and an Android mobile phone. In my PC, say, `C:\Videos`, I have a file `test.mp4`. I want to watch this video "over internet" (not local network) in my android mobile phone. I can achieve this using desktop screen sharing apps like **[Team Viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/)**. But is there any solution to **just stream the file** (in a particular directory), other than sharing entire screen?

In my understanding, there will be a

- desktop client application (which will list the files in directory, and which can stream the file on request)
- an android client, which can connect to my desktop client (in a different network) and provides UI to the user, to list down files in my media directory, and while selecting the file, user will be able to see the video (like youtube)

I cant do this with a local streaming solution like VLC because I don't have static IP. I want to stream over the Internet instead of LAN

Comment: _"I cant do this with a local streaming solution like VLC because I don't have static IP"_ - I don't understand what you mean, could you elaborate? Is streaming over the Internet instead of LAN a requirement?

Comment: @gronostaj yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

For data transfer to occur over a network, some sort of lgical connection hast to be created. It is an intrinsic property of such a connection, that the initiating peer must be able to address (and reach) the accepting peer.

In this scenario, your description of the workflow mirrors exactly what a use of VLC on both ends would be able to do.

Alas, your setup makes this impossible: Neither can your desktop connect to your mobile, nor the other way round.

Teamviewer works around this issue by having both peers connect to their servers (which is easily possible, while the other direction wouldn't be) and the server then facilitates the data flow between the two connections.

So: An easy solution for your problem ist to do exactly that, use a server-based application, that is reachable from both peers, to get the necessary plumbing.

Thank goodness, such an application exists and is free of charge: YouTube livestreams. Set up your desktop to author a YTLS and then use the YT app on your mobile to view it.

Comment: Wow .. Thank you Eugen +1 . Could you tell me is there any tutorial to meet my requirements?

Comment: Also, livestream is public, not private

Comment: You can create private and public livestreams to your liking (I do so all the time, working for the broadcast industry). The tutorial directly by YT (help link in Creator Studio -> Livestreaming) is extremly easy to understand and will get you running within a few minutes.

Comment: I have 1 doubt. I have created YouTube account and it will take 24 ours to verify. No problem. My question is, is it possible for the user to use seek-bar, like in normal YouTube videos? or will it be a video play from beginning to end?

Comment: You were talking of streaming, which allows no seeking. So obviously you can't seek into the future (not-yet streamed part of the video) and by disallowing DVR in the YT settings you can stop seeking into the past.

Answer (score 0):

I could half-solved it by creating an FTP server on the PC and by connecting to it VLC can stream any of the contents without requiring downloading them first. Most of the times it works. There are connection issues sometimes, a stable connection is needed.